# spaCy installation error during cythonisation

Tags: python, xcode, cython, spacy

I am trying to compile spaCy on a macOS Sierra. I just installed XCode and my `gcc --version` shows this:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Installing the requirements works fine, but running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` gives me this error:

```
Obtaining file://~/code/spaCy
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/code/spaCy/spacy/cfile.pyx'
    Processing cfile.pyx
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "~/code/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 157, in <module>
        run(args.root)
      File "~/code/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 148, in run
        process(base, filename, db)
      File "~/code/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 114, in process
        preserve_cwd(base, process_pyx, root + '.pyx', root + '.cpp')
      File "~/code/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 79, in preserve_cwd
        func(*args)
      File "~/code/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 61, in process_pyx
        raise Exception('Cython failed')
    Exception: Cython failed
    Cythonizing sources
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "~/code/spaCy/setup.py", line 227, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "~/code/spaCy/setup.py", line 172, in setup_package
        generate_cython(root, 'spacy')
      File "~/code/spaCy/setup.py", line 104, in generate_cython
        raise RuntimeError('Running cythonize failed')
    RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in ~/code/spaCy/
```

Is there an easy way to debug this? Or am I missing some configuration step?

Comment: The important line is probably "no such file or directory". This looks like you're justing missing a source file.

Comment: I don't see it here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/spacy

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#compile-from-source including `export PYTHONPATH=`pwd``?  What version of spaCy did you download?

Comment: Yes, those are the instructions I followed. Although I tried others too. I am using version `2.0.5` directly pulled from github.